# Application with multitheard looks to work with randomly speed

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote an Java code just for testing how my CPU will run when have to may operation to do so I wrote loop that will add 1 to var in 100000000000 iterations:

```
public class NoThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<=1000000;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<=10000;j++){
                for (int k = 0;k<=10;k++){
                    sum++;
                }
            }
        }
    long k = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time" + (k-s)+ "   " + sum );
    }
}
```

Code finish working after 30 - 40 sec.

Next I decide to split this operation into 10 threads to make my cpu more cry and say my prog to write time when each thread end:

```
public class WithThread {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Runnable[] run = new Runnable[10];
Thread[]thread = new Thread[10];
for (int i = 0; i<=9;i++){
    run[i] = new Counter(i);
    thread[i] = new Thread(run[i]);
        thread[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Counter implements Runnable {
private int inc;
private int incc;
private int sum = 0;
private int id;
public Counter(int a){
    id = a;
    inc = a * 100000;
    incc = (a+1)*100000;
}
@Override
public void run(){
        long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = inc;i<=incc;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<=10000;j++){
                for (int k = 0;k<=10;k++){
                    sum++;  
                }

            }
        }
        long k = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time" + (k-s)+ "   " + sum + " in thread " + id);
    }
}
```

In the result whole code end in 18 - 20 second - so two times faster but when I look at time in each Thread end it works i found something interesting. Each thread had same job to do but 4 threads end work in very short time ( 0,8 second ) and rest of threads ( 6 ) end in 18 to 20 second. I start it again and now i had 6 thread with fast time and 4 with slow. Run it again 7 fast and 3 slow. Amount of fast and slow thread looks randomly. So my question is why there is so big difference between fast and slow threads. Why amount of fast and slow threads is so random, and is this Language specific (Java) or maybe operating system, CPU or something else ?

Comment: How much MIPS has the comp?

Comment: Oh i do not know :D It was tested on i3 2350 m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before moving into the working process of Threads and Processors, I'll explain it in more understandable way.

**Scenario**

```
Location A ------------------------------ Location B
     |     |_____________________________|
     |                     |
     |                200 Metres
     |
     |              Have to be carried to
400 Bags of Sand -------------------------- Location B
(In Location A)
```

So, the worker will have to carry each Sand Bag from Location A to Location B until all the Sandbags are moved to location B.

Lets just pretend that the worker will be instantly Teleported back (for argument sake) to Location A (but not the other way around) once he arrives at Location B.

**Case 1**

*Number of Workforce = 1 (No.of Mens)*

*Time taken = 2 mins (Time for Moving 1 SandBag from Location A to Location B)*

Total time taken to carry `400 Sandbags` from Location A to Location B will be

*Totaltime Taken = 2 x 400 = 800 mins*

**Case 2**

*Number of Workforce = 4 (No.of Mens)*

*Time taken = 2 mins (Time for Moving 1 SandBag from Location A to Location B)*

So now we're going to split the job equally among the available workforce.

*Assigned Sandbag for Each worker = 400 / 4 = 100*

Lets say everyone is starting their job at the same time.

Total time taken for carrying 100 Sandbags from Location A to Location B for an individual workforce

*TimeTaken for Individual Workforce = 2 x 100 = 200 mins*

Since everyone had started their job at the same time, all the `400 Sandbags` will be carried from Location A to Location B in `200 mins`

**Case 3**

*Number of Workforce = 4 (No.of Mens)*

Here, lets say that every men has to carry 4 sandbags from Location A to Location B in a single transfer.

*Total Sandbags in Single transfer for every worker = 4 bags*

*Time taken = 12 mins (Time for Moving 4 SandBags from Location A to Location B in a single transfer)*

Since everyone is forced to carry 4 sandbags with them instead of 1, this is greatly reduce their speed.

Even consider this,

1) I ordered you to carry 1 sandbag from A to B, you'll take 2 mins.

2) I ordered you to carry 2 sandbags from A to B at one transfer, you'll take 5 mins instead of theoritical 4 mins, because this is due to our body conditions and the weight we're carrying.

3) I ordered you to carry 4 sandbags from A to B at one transfer, you'll take 12 mins instead of (Theoritical 8 mins in Point 1, Theoritical 10 mins in Point 2), which is also because of human nature.

So now we're going to split the job equally among the available workforce.

*Assigned Sandbag for Each worker = 400 / 4 = 100*

*Total transfers for Each worker = 100 / 4 = 25 Transfers*

Calculating the time taken for single worker to complete his full job

*Total time for Single worker = 12 mins x 25 tranfers = 300*

So, they've taken an additional 100 min instead of theoritical 200 mins (Case 2)

**Case 4**

*Total Sandbags in Single transfer for every worker = 100 bags*

Since this is impossible to do by anyone, so he'll just quit.

```
xx--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------xx
```

This is the same kind of working principle in Threads and Processors

Here

**Workforce = No. of Processors**

**Total Sandbags = No.of Threads**

**Sandbags in a Single transfer = No.of threads a (1) processor is going to handle simultaneously**

Assume

*Available Processors = 4*

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()  // -> Syntax to get the no of available processors
```

**Note:** Link every Case with the Realtime Case explained above

**Case 1**

```
for (int i=0;i<=1000000;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<=10000;j++){
        for (int k = 0;k<=10;k++){
            sum++;  
        }
    }
}
```

Whole operation is series process, so it'll take execution time what it's suppose to.

**Case 2**

```
for( int n = 1; n <= 4; n++ ){  
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        void run(){
            for (int i=0;i<=250000;i++){     // 1000000 / 4 = 250000
                for (int j=0;j<=10000;j++){
                    for (int k = 0;k<=10;k++){
                        sum++;  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Here each processor will going to handle 1 thread. So it'll take 1/4th of the actual time.

**Case 3**

```
for( int n = 1; n <= 16; n++ ){  
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        void run(){
            for (int i=0;i<=62500;i++){     // 1000000 / 16 = 62500
                for (int j=0;j<=10000;j++){
                    for (int k = 0;k<=10;k++){
                        sum++;  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Totally 16 threads will be created and each processor will have to handle 4 threads simultaneously. So practically, it'll increase the processor load to its max, thus it'll reduce the efficiency of the processor resulting in increase in the execution time of each processor.

Totally it'll take `1/4th of(1/4th of actual time) + performace degrade time(will definitely be higher than than the 1/4th of actual time)`

**Case 4**

```
for( int n = 1; n <= 100000; n++ ){       // 100000 - Just for argument sake
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        void run(){
            for (int i=0;i<=1000000;i++){     
                for (int j=0;j<=10000;j++){
                    for (int k = 0;k<=10;k++){
                        sum++;  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

At this stage, creating and starting a thread is more expensive (if the processor already have more threads in it) than the time taken for creating and starting previous threads.As the number of simultaneous threads increases, it'll hugely increase the processor load until the processor reaches its capacity, thus lead to System Crash.

The reason why your threads created in the first were having less execution time is because there wont be any performance degrade in processor during the intital stage. But as the for loop continues, no of threads have to be handled by each processor increases beyond the fair ratio (1:1), so you'll start to experience lag when the threads counts were increased in processor.

Comment: _Creating and starting a thread is more expensive than executing the operations inside that thread._  If that were true, then we would not use multiple threads for computation.  Ever.  It would always be cheaper to do all computations in a single thread.  The reality is, creating and starting a thread has a fixed cost.  It's not worthwhile to create a thread that will only live for a few microseconds, but it _is_ worthwhile to create a thread that will run for minutes or weeks or months.

Comment: @jameslarge, I was bit wrong about that line. Will change it later. My idea is to explain him that the fixed cost will be a huge burden on processors if the processors already have more created threads which are in execution.

Comment: Nice explanation. But maybe i'm just poor on my mind but in that way why does 2 core procesor with 4 threads run those "fast" threads so randomly ? One it can handle 3 of them in second time it can handle more than 7 ?

Comment: @Aht, Its very common in all languages. If an operation completes in 2.14 sec (for eg..) for first time, you cannot expect same time for same operation from next time. Its not random..! To be more specific, it all depends on current status / factors of your computer. If you want to test it, open many cpu and ram comsuming application / tasks, then run your program and note down the time taken. Then close all application and run your program, you could see that time taken now is very less when comparing with previous time coz of the ram and cpu consumption by other apps in previous execution.